# How to append stopwords from being in a text file without using nltk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text, stop-words

```
import re 

input_file = open('documents.txt', 'r')
stopwords = open('stopwords.txt', 'r')

word_count = {}
for line in input_file.readlines():
    words = line.strip()
    words = re.findall('\w+', line)
    for word in words: 
      word = word.lower()
      if not word in word_count: 
        word_count[word] = 1
      else: 
        word_count[word] = word_count[word] + 1

word_index = sorted(word_count.keys())
for word in word_index:
  print (word, word_count[word])
```

Currently as is, this code outputs the frequency of times a word appears in the input_files text document.

However, I need to omit stopwords that are found in the stopwords.txt document - I am unable to use nltk for this.

What's the most efficient way to essentially say

```
#For each line you read in input_file.readlines()
  #if a word in input_file is in stopwords
    #append it
  #else
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `set` datastructure that has `O(1)` time complexity membership testing:

```
stop_words = set(["in", "to", "this", ...])
if word in stop_words:
    print("discarded")
```

---

```
import re 

input_file = open('documents.txt', 'r')
stopwords_file = 'stopwords.txt'
stopwords_list = []

with open(stopwords_file) as f:
    stopwords_list = [line.replace("\n", "") for line in f.readlines()]

stopwords_set = set(stopwords_list)

word_count = {}
for line in input_file.readlines():
    words = line.strip()
    words = re.findall('\w+', line)
    for word in words:
      if word.lower() in stopwords_set:
        continue
      word = word.lower()
      if not word in word_count: 
        word_count[word] = 1
      else: 
        word_count[word] = word_count[word] + 1

word_index = sorted(word_count.keys())
for word in word_index:
  print (word, word_count[word])
```

Comment: The issue is that I need to use the stopwords.txt file that is being opened. And from there - if any stopword is present in the documents.txt, it needs to be appended from documents.txt. If that makes sense - I can't just print discared.

Comment: @user14452102 Yes, I understand that my answer is not a full solution, but it contains a very efficient tool for the job, the rest of the code you will have to find out for yourself, if you have any specific question feel free to ask.

Comment: I don't even know where to begin. Do I need to build a separate function? Can I read two text files at once to compare if a word in Txt Doc A is in Txt Doc B, how can you apply set to a list of words from a Text doc. I'm clearly a beginner - I don't understand, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: @user14452102 I suggest first of all read the first file and from it build your set of stopword, then use the set to filter the second file

Comment: @user14452102 Google is an extremely powerful tool, you can search: "How to read a file in Python" or "How to read words from a file in Python" to get some material to start for the first task

Comment: I came to StackOverFlow to be given some direction or assistance in a more hands-on way as I've been Googling for the past hour. You asked for more specific questions, I asked, you told me to Google it. If you aren't going to be helpful, please stop responding. I've been in the hospital all week and don't need to be lectured on search engines. Thanks

Comment: @user14452102 To help you more I need to know the format of the input file, can you please post a small section of that file?

Comment: The input file is #1 The cat in the hat is on the mat. #2 The rat sat on the mat. New lines come after #1, The #2, and The

Comment: @user14452102 I gave you some more details on how to approach the problem, in my approach I assume one stopword for each line, so not exactly the same of yours but it can give you a starting point

Comment: The stopword text file is one stopword for each line. The input document file is what we want to remove stopwords from

Comment: @user14452102 perfect, can you try the example code I wrote in the answer?

Comment: Thank you. The code fails because with open is having trouble reading a text file, as it is expecting a string.

Comment: @user14452102 hey I fixed the error you mentioned

Comment: The output is still not removing the stopwords from the documents file. Do you know what is wrong? It is essentially the same exact output from the code I originally wrote out - so words in stopwords.txt such as "an," "the" are still showing up and being counted

Comment: try printing the `stopwords_list`

Comment: Example of the beginning of my output: ['a\n', 'about\n', 'above\n', 'across\n', 'after\n', 'afterwards\n', 'again\n', 'against\n', 'all\n', 'almost\n', 'alone\n', 'along\n', 'already\n', 'also\n', 'although\n', 'always\n', 'am\n', 'among\n', 'amongst\n', 'amoungs...So the list is there but not omitting from documents.

Comment: I don't know if it helps or hurts, but stopwords.txt is about 300 lines with one word per line. i.e. line one is a, line 2 is about, line 3 is above, etc and so on.

Comment: I was able to fix it - my only remaining question is - I also need to remove punctuation from inside the text document - is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: @user14452102 yes, you can `doc.replace('.', '').replace(',','')` and so on for the various punctations

Comment: Is that within the for line in input_file loop? What would that look like?

Comment: @user14452102 yes, at the start of the loop `line = line.replace(...)`

Comment: Oh, I ended up using ...under line.strip()  words = words.translate(str.maketrans('','', string.punctuation)).. Does this still work? I imported string library

Comment: @user14452102 You have to look at the output and decide if it is correct or not depending on your goals

Comment: If possible can you also help me try and troubleshoot next step? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75250373/in-python-how-to-parse-one-text-document-into-separate-dictionaries-based-on-l